# Should there always be a ripple on electric field lines at а constant movement?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

If you launch [this applet](https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/radiating-charge/radiating-charge_en.html) you'll see a charge and field lines that propagate from this charge with finite speed. Why when charge moves, the lines move instantly with charge but not like below

[image]

Interesting, because this is actually the of picture of accelerated charge.

Okay, what is incorrect - applet animation, or my understanding(that requires perpendicular curve due to constant move)?

I think that there always should be a small(perhaps, depend on velocity) ripple
 at а constant movement

Comment: Related :  (1)  [Electric field associated with moving charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/296904/)----(2)  [Does a classic physics describes the electric charges forces propagation speed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/424234/).----(3)...

Comment: @Frobenius, but I didn't ask especially about the stuff above

Comment: ....Related : ----(3) [Why does an accelerated charge radiate away energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/426608/).

Comment: I gave related not duplicate.

Comment: @Frobenius didn't understand the answer on the last related question. Guy meant "stirs up", when charge didn't move and then start? It's an acceleration. Or, yet there will be stirs every time, charge move(constantly), which means that applet wrong?

Comment: The Liénard–Wiechert potentials/fields are the potentials/fields of a moving charge

Comment: @Triatticus, so I am correct?

Comment: Your suspicions are correct yes, the lines won't move along with the charge, this is because of the finite speed of light. So distortions in the field take time to propagate outwards.