# Why do field lines kink when a charge is accelerated and not at constant speed?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, antennas

The emission of electromagnetic waves is sometimes explained by drawing field lines that "kink" when the charge is accelerated. The kink is then said to be an EM wave.
[image]
The kink formation  are explained by the far field not adjusting instantaneously to the move in the charge emitting the field.
I do not understand why that would be the case when the charge accelerates and not when the charge is moving at constand speed. In both cases there has to be a delay in the far field adjustment and therefore an EM wave. Could you please explain what I am missing  in this visual explanation of why EM are emitted only when the charge is accelerating ?

[source](https://youtu.be/ZaXm6wau-jc?t=101)
see also https://youtu.be/6lb040GCs2M?t=735

Comment: This question is solved here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/428922/why-doesnt-a-charged-particle-moving-with-constant-velocity-produce-electromagn

Comment: I like the answers related to frames of references thanks. Yes you can answer with maxwell too, but it doesnt quite spell out the answer asked for here or there, the one about the kinks in the EM field lines. Perhaps that's why no answer was choosen there. Perhaps my question, being more graphic, will have merit

Comment: @ManudeHanoi hey. Did you find an answer to this ?

Comment: @Chemistry I found a simulator that shows electric field lines do not bend when a single charge is moving at constant speed, I don't really understand why